# How to return None while declaring Class instance

Tags: python

`MyClass` which is defined below accepts a single argument `arg`.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        if not isinstance(arg, int):
            return None
        else:
            self.arg = arg
```

If the incoming argument `arg` is not an integer I would like to return None instead of the instance of `MyClass`.

```
a = MyClass(arg='Text Argument')
```

But even while `MyClass` constructor `__init__` returns None when the `arg` is not an integer the resulting variable `a` is still an instance of `MyClass`:

```
print a
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000000001FDEFD0>
```

How to make sure the variable `a` remains `None` if `MyClass` is given a non-integer argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not return `None` from a constructor, even if it was possible. The result of `MyClass()` should always be an instance of `MyClass` or a compatible class; anything else would be Very Surprising And Error Inducing Behaviour™.

You *could* do this with a custom `__new__` method, which creates the actual instance. But again, I would not recommend it.

You *should* be raising an exception if the object cannot be constructed with the given data:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        if not isinstance(arg, int):
            raise TypeError('arg must be an int')

        ...
```

Comment: Explicitly returning `None` is OK (or just `return` by itself) since that's what will happen by default. You could do it early to exit the `__init__()` method early, I suppose, but doing so doesn't affect whether the instance gets created or not—just possibly the initial state it's given.

Comment: True, that was worded somewhat ambiguously. I meant *if the return value would make any difference, you still shouldn't do it.*

Comment: Regardless of what you meant, my point was that what you're saying isn't accurate: Not only is it possible, there's conceivably a reason to do it knowing full well that it's not going to prevent the instance from being created. Which doesn't appear to be what the OP wishes to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You generally should not be doing this, but you could if you want to, by *overriding* your `__new__`, where the **new instance** is created:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(kwargs['arg'], int):
            return None
        return super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
```

The `__init__` method does not **create** the instance, it only initializes it, returning `None` from it is what is expected.

In the case `__new__` returns an object that is not an instance (like `None` in this case), `__init__` will not be called.

One of the reasons why you should not use the above is the following:

```
print isinstance(MyClass(arg='666'), MyClass) #-> False
# waaah!
```

A lot of things will start to break in your code, and the above is only just one example.